# I want to make a booking system in java, and I cannot check the dates given between another dates

Tags: java, date

I want to make a booking system for rooms. The user will insert a date from startDate to endDate. Alright, after thats lets say that another user will want to book the same room in between the same dates as the user.So, if the first user booked the room from 2017-1-1(yyyy-MM-dd) to 2017-1-8, the next user cannot book the same room in exactly these dates or from 2017-1-3 to 2017-1-10.the user will be informed that he/she can book only before 1/1 or after 1/8.

Here is my code:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String startDateFirst = "2016-1-1";
        String endDateFirst = "2016-1-4";

        Date convertedStartDateFirst = convertDate(startDateFirst);
        Date convertedEndDateFirst = convertDate(endDateFirst);

        List<Date> myList = new ArrayList<Date>(getDaysBetweenDates(convertedStartDateFirst,convertedEndDateFirst));


        String startDate2 = "2016-1-1";
        String endDate2 = "2016-1-3";

        Date convDateStr2 = convertDate(startDate2);
        Date convDateEnd2 = convertDate(endDate2);

        List<Date> myListSecond = new ArrayList<Date>(getDaysBetweenDates(convDateStr2,convDateEnd2));

        System.out.println("FIRST BOOKING: " + getDaysBetweenDates(convertedStartDateFirst,convertedEndDateFirst));
        System.out.println("SECOND BOOKING: " + getDaysBetweenDates(convDateStr2,convDateEnd2));


       for (int i=0; i<=myListSecond.size(); i++)
        {

                if ((myList.get(i).getTime() >= myListSecond.get(i).getTime() && myList.get(i).getTime() <= myListSecond.get(i).getTime())) {
                    System.out.println(myListSecond.get(i) + " is taken");
                } else if (myList.get(i).equals(myListSecond.get(i))) {
                    System.out.println(myListSecond.get(i) + " equal");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(myListSecond.get(i) + "is not");
                }


        }



    }

    public static Date convertDate(String strDate)
    {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
        try{
            Date date = format.parse(strDate);
            //String finalDate = format.format(date);
            return date;
        }catch (ParseException e)
        {

        }
        return null;
    }
    public static List<Date> getDaysBetweenDates(Date startdate, Date enddate)
    {
        List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.setTime(startdate);

        while (calendar.getTime().before(enddate))`enter code here`
        {
            Date result = calendar.getTime();
            dates.add(result);
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
        }
        return dates;
    }

}
```

Although, in `getDaysBetweenDates` I get the date but with -1 date, why? and how do I return the exactly dates.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works.  Questions of the form _"I want to do X, please show me what to change in my code"_ are considered off-topic.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at joda time: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/, it's a nice API to make calculations with dates, much better and less error prone than Calendar

Comment: @Hugo The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the java.time classes.

Comment: @BasilBourque This applies only if you're using java 8. For projects with java 7 I still use joda

Comment: @Hugo Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 and Java 7 In the ThreeTen-Backport project. Led by Stephen Colebourne, same man behind Joda-Time and java.time. Further adapted for Android in the ThreeTenABP project. So no need to suggest Joda-Time except for a few feature differences.

Comment: @BasilBourque I didn't know about this project, very interesting! Thanks

Comment: Joda-Time continues to be actively updated, so no urgent need to migrate. But generally I would suggest new work in old Java use the back-port rather than Joda-Time.

Answer (score 1):

The way to determine whether two bookings overlap in time, that is, conflict, is actually easier than one would first expect.

Two bookings are free from conflict if one comes before the other:

```
(convDateStr2 equal to or after convertedEndDateFirst)
        or (convertedStartDateFirst equal to or after convDateEnd2)
```

I am giving you pseudocode, you can do the translation to Java yourself. I’ll give you a few tips for that at the bottom of this answer. Please note that you don’t need to find the dates between start and end for this.

Conversely, two bookings overlap/conflict if

```
(convDateStr2 before convertedEndDateFirst)
        and (convertedStartDateFirst before convDateEnd2)
```

I basically just inverted the first expression.

If you are using the `Date` class, you may use its `before`, `equals` and/or `after` methods. Similarly for `LocalDate` (Java 8 or one of the backports) the methods are `isAfter()`, `isBefore`, `isEqual()` and `equals()`.